# Translation of "Are you ok?" or "Are you alright?"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

What is the best Spanish translation of the English phrase "Are you ok?" or "Are you alright?" (said out of concern for someone who has just gotten hurt, for example after tripping and falling or getting hit by a ball thrown at them)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct translation would be "¿Estás bien?" or "¿Te encuentras bien?". Maybe we use more "¿Estás bien?" for general things and "¿Te encuentras bien?" for ask about feelings. Anyway, you can use both for the same purpose.

Comment: I would use "¿Te encuentras bien?" especially if i knew the person was sick or not feeling very well and "¿Estás bien?" more generally like Sergi mentioned =)

Comment: I'm thinking more a situation where someone has just gotten hurt, rather than them feeling bad in general.

Comment: Then I'll use "¿Estás bien?"

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the two ways provided by Sergi, if you want to check if someones alright after getting hurt like you mentioned, you could also ask:

> ¿Se siente bien? - Do you feel alright?
>
> ¿Te has hecho daño? - Are you hurt? (after tripping over/falling etc)
>
> ¿Estás herido? - Are you hurt? (wounded)