# How to translate 'alright' when used as a trait (as in "being alright at racing")?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, adjetivos

I'm having a rough time finding the best translation for [this J. Taylor tweet](https://twitter.com/jordan10taylor/status/1089297264181420038) made during Fernando Alonso's first stint in the 24 Hours of Daytona race:

> This [Alonso] guy seems alright.

[image: This [Alonso] guy seems alright.]

Ok, so we all know 'alright' means *bien*:

- "Everything's alright" → *"Todo está bien"*
- ["Are you alright?" → *"¿Estás bien?"*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1422/13628), etc.

In these examples, 'alright' is used to describe the *state* of something/someone -- the kind that'd force you to [use *"estar"* instead of *"ser"*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19836/13628) in Spanish.

In the above tweet, however, 'alright' is being used **as a *trait***: the kind we use *"ser"* with — like saying Alonso seems "OK at racing" (at least that's how I understood it).
And this is where the rough part begins, because everything I come up with seems slightly off. For staters, Google Translate seems to disagree with my interpretation, and [translates](https://translate.google.es/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=es&text=This%20Alonso%20guy%20seems%20alright) it as just *"Este chico Alonso parece estar bien"*, but that looks like we're talking about his health. As for me, I've tried:

- *"parece bueno"*, but I think someone being *"bueno"* at something is a tad over being just 'alright' at something;
- *"parece aceptable"*, *"parece decente"*... but those don't give the same informal vibe that 'alright' does.

Maybe I'm just overthinking this, but whatever.
**What would be the best translation for 'alright' in this context?**

---

EDIT: Looking at the current answers, it seems like there are more types of 'alright' than I thought!
Please notice that I'm asking specifically about **being 'alright' *at something***:

> [...] like saying Alonso seems "OK at racing" (at least that's how I understood it). [...] I've tried *"parece bueno"*, but I think someone being *"bueno"* at something is a tad over being just 'alright' at something.

Comment: It seems to me that this may be an example of meiosis and in fact the tweeter thinks he is really very good. I am not sure how widespread that figure of speech is in Spanish.

Comment: "Joe Bloe is alright at racing" = Fulano... no está mal [y el contexto nos dará lo demás].  Esto me parece una traducción bastante precisa, de hecho.  O si quieres un variante un poquito más entusiasmado: Fulano...no está nada mal. // La expresión en inglés podría ser un tanto irónica (pero quizás ya sabías).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use:

> Parece un tío majo/legal/[guay](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Jmj5DLi).

I have seen [a comment in the Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=alright) that says:

> [When] you call a person 'alright' you are saying that they are amazing, awesome, brilliant, and you want to love them.

If this is true (it seems so according to [@mdewey's comment](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/28451/how-to-translate-alright-when-used-as-a-trait/28454#comment49189_28451)) you can even say:

> Parece un tío genial/fantástico/etc.

---

After your edit it seems that we misunderstood your question. You actually wanted to translate "being alright *at something*", so I will stick to @mdewey's comment then and propose the following.

> No se le da mal a Alonso [eso de conducir].

I think this sentence keeps the feeling of saying that he is actually very good at it while stating that he is just "not bad".

Answer (score 2):

Your last examples seem close to what you mean; but if you're looking for an informal touch, I'd say

> Parece buen tipo.

Or variations like *parece un buen tipo*.

This denotes a friendly deal and trust, so you can also use more formal adjectives like *fiable* or *confiable*, or more informally: *parece de fiar*.